# Sh’ma time on a long travel

Tags: zemanim, shema, travel, contemporary-halacha

If one is traveling a very long distance, for example an El Al flight from Los Angeles to Tel Aviv, at what time should they recite the Sh’ma?

Would it be based on the time of departure, the time they experience in the plane, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the OU [writes](https://outorah.org/p/33372/) "**always say the prayer service based on the day and time where you are at the moment you are ready to pray**"

To calculate the right times, you can use tools such as [The Chai Tables](http://chaitables.com/chai_air_eng.php?look=20231016) or [MyZmanim](https://www.myzmanim.com/airdemo.aspx).

Comment: If I recall, when eastbound on an overnight flight, the time window is not that long, and often when most folks are still sleeping / lights off / shutters down.

Comment: You are right, if you leave late evening e.g., from East Coast to Israel, morning comes very fast (esp. in the summer), and you are typically asleep. Only solution is a strong wake up call or to take an earlier flight where hopefully you can sleep a bit before the need to pray